# Battlefield 2: 32/64 player map mods in single-player and impact on online play

Tags: mods, battlefield-2

I'm a very casual gamer these days and happen to quite enjoy the single-player mode of Battlefield 2. However, I like the 32/64 player maps from the online/multi-player version. It seems there are some mods which open up the 32/64 player maps in single-player, but will these mods impact my ability to play online multiplayer? (i.e Will I get issues with Punkbuster?)

Comment: If you modify the game files then Punkbuster will be able to detect those changes. You will need to explain how Battlefield 2 handles user modifications if you want your second half of your question answered.